# Why is my program only printing my last number instead of all of the input numbers?

Tags: c, for-loop

The problem I was given to solve is "The number of students who will take the exam is entered from the keyboard, and then the IDs of all the students who will take the exam are entered. The program should divide the students into three groups: students with IDs ending in the digits 0, 1, and 2, students with IDs ending in the digits 3, 4, 5, and students with IDs ending in the digits 6, 7, 8, 9 .The program should print the IDs for each group, in the same order as they were entered. The maximum number of students that can be entered is 1000.".

The code that I can come up with is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int n,br,gr1,gr2,gr3;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &br);

        if (br % 10 == 0 || br % 10 == 1 || br % 10 == 2) 
{
            gr1 = br;
        } 
else if (br % 10 == 3 || br % 10 == 4 || br % 10 == 5) 
{
            gr2 = br;
        } 
else if (br % 10 == 6 || br % 10 == 7 || br % 10 == 8 || br % 10 == 9) 
{
            gr3 = br;
        }
    }
    printf("Grupa 1\n%d\n",gr1);
    printf("Grupa 2\n%d\n",gr2);
    printf("Grupa 1\n%d\n",gr3);

return 0;
}
```

Instead of printing all the IDs and sorting them into groups it is only printing the last input number and group number.
I am in no way an experienced programmer so I can't really tell what is wrong with the way I have written this or how to solve it. I would appreciate it if you can guide me through

The output I am expecting is:

```
Grupa 1
20010 20581 19452
Grupa 2
20145 19873 19825 20653
Grupa 3
20147 20139 19458
```

The output I am getting is

```
Grupa 1
19452
Grupa 2
20653
Grupa 3
19458
```

Comment: Indent your code properly. Your `if` statements are not inside the `for` loop.

Comment: @The code posted here does not need to match your homework, nor the program checker.  Format for clarity here.

Answer (score 1):

The way you format you code makes it harder for yourself to figure out what is going on.  You need to stash in a data in an ordered data structure (array, linked list etc):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STUDENTS 1000
typedef size_t student_id;

enum group {
    GROUP_1 = 1,
    GROUP_2,
    GROUP_3
};

enum group group_student(student_id id) {
    switch(id % 10) {
        case 0: case 1: case 2:
            return GROUP_1;
        case 3: case 4: case 5:
            return GROUP_2;
        default:
            return GROUP_3;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    student_id ids[MAX_STUDENTS];
    size_t n = 0; // required below
    for(; n < sizeof ids / sizeof *ids; n++) {
        if(scanf("%zu", ids + n) != 1) {
            break;
        }
    }
    for(enum group group = GROUP_1; group <= GROUP_3; group++) {
        printf("Grupa %d\n", group);
        for(size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if(group == group_student(ids[j]))
                printf("%zu ", ids[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

and here is an example run:

```
$ echo '20010 20581 19452 20145 19873 19825 20653 20147 20139 19458' | ./a.out
Grupa 1
20010 20581 19452 
Grupa 2
20145 19873 19825 20653 
Grupa 3
20147 20139 19458
```

When you type this in, end input with ctrl-D.  I used a `enum group` here as it's an identifier (not a number) and documents by virtue of the return type that you change the enum you want to change the function `group_student()`, too.

Comment: While it is correct and I tried that, my expected output is Grupa 1
20010 20581 19452
Grupa 2
20145 19873 19825 20653
Grupa 3
20147 20139 19458
Instead of printing it every time I input numbers it should be printed in the end with all the output numbers together in heir respective groups

Comment: So you changed the question after I answered your original question, right?  It's better to accept the answer and submit another question.  Read the data you need to print afterwards into an array then print the array afterwards.  Do you know how many values you need to read for each group or only the total number `n`?

Comment: I changed the question because I saw how people could get confused by what I wrote and I wanted to rewrite it more clearly. I am not meant to use arrays, and I don't really know how to solve it without arrays. I need to read all the values that I have input so long as the number is not more than 1000

Comment: I revised answer to match the new requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Your gr1,gr2,gr3 int variables can only store one values at a time (here, the last value that was assigned to it so its showing only one result.) Make them something like an array eg gr1[],gr2[],gr3[], which will be able to hold multiple values at a time and will be able to print them out at the end.

Comment: Is there any way to do that without arrays? Since we have not yet really learned them and this is some optional homework I am trying to have a crack at.

Comment: @Kratos1919 — there isn't really a sensible way to do it without using arrays.  Mechanisms could be devised: for example, you could open/create three files, one for each group, and write the data to the correct file as you're reading the input, then read the files one at a time to print the results.  But it is clumsy by comparison with using arrays.

Comment: I understand, but I don't think they are meant to be used since we still don't "really know" what they are and how to use them. I have been scratching my head for the past couple of hours since I don't really know how to solve this and get to the correct output

Comment: @Kratos1919 the only other way I could think of is casting the br into strings and concatenating each results into a string gr1, gr2, gr3 and printing out that concatenated result at the end. Eg, if br = 20581 then check br % 10 == 1 (true) then cast that br into a string/char and add it to string gr1. Then print that gr1 at the end so gr1 could be a string like gr1 = "20010 20581 19452" instead of individual integers